# Проблема с форомой обратной связи на Live

Tags: php, javascript, form

Возможно, кто то сталкивался с подобным: 
Лендинг на локалке работает на 100%,  поднял на live и завис с багом: форма обратой связи перестала работать. Спустил снова на локалку, в отдельную папку - все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: спасибо. сейчас гляну

Comment: Логи пустые.  такое впечатление что до исполнения скрипта вообще не доходит.